# Expected number of directed cycle in a directed complete graph

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, directed-graphs

Consider the randomized, directed complete graph G = (V, E) where for each pair of vertices u, v ∈ V, we add either the directed edge (u → v) or the directed edge (v → u) chosen uniformly at random. What is the expected number of directed cycles of 3 vertices, as a function of the number of vertices n?

Comment: A good question, but too simple for MO.

Comment: @JohnCartor, this kind of graph is called a random [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)). This keyword might help you find information elsewhere.